# Custom page template not working on mobile

Tags: page-template, child-theme, mobile, responsive

I have a child theme. Within the child theme, I have a custom page template. It work perfectly on a desktop. It is not working on my iPhone with the Safari browser.

This is the template:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); //This code stops the theme files from loading

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    the_content();
endwhile; 

//Get post ID - create html element to store it
echo "<div id=postID>".get_the_ID()."</div>" ;

?>
```

Notice how the template does not load the theme files, header or footer. Yet when I open the page on my iPhone, the header and footer are there. In addition to that, all the theme files are loaded. It seems as though the template is being ignored on mobile.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you really think that theme's templates are so smart to understand are you mobile or not?

Comment: Really, you define `WP_USE_THEMES` **in a template** that is loaded by the theme?

Comment: Everything works perfectly on desktop but not on mobile. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The Jetpack plugin has its own mobile theme, which is overriding the child theme.